# How to find custom unique values in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, formula, array-formulas

I have the following values in Excel: `{"Apple", "Orange", "Orange", "Banana", "Apple}`.
If I run the *Unique* formula on this array, then it will return `{"Apple", "Orange", "Banana"}`.

The problem is that sometimes I have typos in my Excel values, so I might have the following values: `{"Apple", "Applee", "Orange", "Orange", "Orang", "Banana", "Apple}`. This way, the *Unique* formula would return the following array: `{"Applee", "Orange", "Orang", "Banana", "Apple}`, however, I would like it to return `{"Apple", "Orange", "Banana"}`. The count values without typos are always higher than the count of values with typos.

What I would like to do, is that if the given cell has less than 3 unique characters then values which are already in the list, then do not count it as a Unique value.

Is it possible to do with only built-in formulas? I would try to **avoid using VBA** at nearly any cost.

Comment: There's just no reason you should do this. It's way over-complicated, and can be solved by just using a data validation rule which prevents typos.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249

Comment: @Kwright02 data validation is not an option. Please help me!

Comment: [Fuzzy matching in Power Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/fuzzy-matching) might be helpful?

Comment: @Marci why is Data validation not an option? it's built into excel

Comment: The problem comes when you have valid unique but are close matches: `Cherry` and `Berry`  if you do not have a list of valid values, there is no way for Excel to know that these count as valid unique entries.  They have 4 letters in common and one would get skipped by your 3 letter rule.  What they are saying is that you should control the data entry with a set drop down list the user can choose from instead of trying to deal with human error.

Comment: Exactly. If you can define what's a typo, it can be calculated, if you can't define it, what should be calculated?

Comment: I can define, however, I would like someone to provide me a guide/formula to achieve the calculation.

Comment: Have you tried something silly like running Spell Check?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve what you're asking for is to maintain a list of commonly misspelled words and their corresponding correct words. If the list is relatively short, you could use the `SWITCH()` function; if not, it would be easier to use `XLOOKUP()` with a separate lookup table.

**Example 1:** The `SWITCH()` function

```
=SWITCH(D2:D15, "Applee","Apple", "Appel","Apple", "Banaan","Banana", "Orang","Orange", "Oranges","Orange", D2:D15)
```

`SWITCH()` looks at each value in range `D2:D15` and replaces any matching values found with their corresponding results. Matching values and results are entered in pairs and can include up to 126 pairs in total. The final optional argument is the default value to be returned if no match is found, which in this case is the original value present in range `D2:D15`.

**Results 1:**

[image: switch_function.png]

**Note:** the formula used to generate the unique list in the above screenshot is `=SORT(UNIQUE(F2#))` and the formula to return the counts for each unique item is `=COUNTIF(F2#, H2#)`. Monitor the unique list for any newly misspelled words and update the `SWITCH()` formula as they occur.

**Example 2:** `XLOOKUP()` with separate lookup table

```
=IFNA(XLOOKUP(D2:D15, K2:K6, L2:L6), D2:D15)
```

In this example, the misspelled words are listed in range `K2:K6` with the corresponding correct words in range `L2:L6`. The `IFNA()` function is used to return the original value from range `D2:D15` if no match is found by `XLOOKUP()`, because the optional *[if_not_found]* parameter will not accept a range of values.

**Results 2:**

[image: xlookup_function.png]

**Example 3:** `XLOOKUP()` with structured table references

```
=IFNA(XLOOKUP([@Item], Table2[Incorrect], Table2[Correct]), [@Item])
```

This is the same method as Example 2, but with Excel tables. The above formula is used to create a calculated column in **Table1**, and the list of incorrect/correct words are stored in **Table2**.

**Results 3:**

[image: xlookup_tables.png]

**Note:** the formula used to generate the unique list in the above screenshot is `=SORT(UNIQUE(Table1[Corrected]))` and the formula to return the counts for each unique item is `=COUNTIF(Table1[Corrected], G2#)`.

Answer (score -1):

If you set up your correct values in a column, and then define the possible typos in the cells to the right on the same row then you could use this formula
[image: Screenshot illustrating suggested formula]

```
=UNIQUE(MAP({"Apple","Applee","Orange","Orange","Orng","Banna","Apple"},LAMBDA(a,INDEX(F1:F3,INT((MATCH(1,TOROW(--(a=F1:I3)),0)-1)/4)+1,1))),TRUE)
```

(the `/4` is because there are 4 columns in the 'lookup' range - `F1:I3`)

Comment: Too many variations on incorrect spelling for this to work.  Aples, pples appples, applse, appels, appls, appes just as a quick start and I could probably come up with at least a dozen more ways to misspell Apples.

Comment: @FrankBall [bluff called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3frv.png)